# Menu item setTitle

Tags: java, android, null, menuitem, object-reference

I would like to change the title of an item in a menu, but I get an error, here is the log:

```
E: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.locateit.antholife.locateit, PID: 18329
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.MenuItem.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
   at com.locateit.antholife.locateit.Main2Activity.onPrepareOptionsMenu(Main2Activity.java:786)
   at android.app.Activity.onPreparePanel(Activity.java:3150)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPrepareOptionsPanel(FragmentActivity.java:530)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPreparePanel(FragmentActivity.java:519)
   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:93)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onPreparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:297)
   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:93)
   at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$ToolbarCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(ToolbarActionBar.java:567)
   at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:455)
   at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:61)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
   at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:133)
```

I do not understand why it makes to a null object reference..

Here is the java file:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.vue, menu);
    this.menu = menu;
    return true;
```

then ;

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuItem titredistance = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_distance);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(
                            "appSharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String lat1 = sharedPreferences.getString("lat", null);
    String lng1 = sharedPreferences.getString("lng", null);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Main2Activity.this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) 
                                getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(
                                locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));

        if (lat1 != null) {
            if (lng1 != null) {
                if (location != null) {

                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        double latl = location.getLatitude();
                        double lngl = location.getLongitude();

                        double lat = Double.parseDouble(lat1);
                        double lng = Double.parseDouble(lng1);

                        Location locationA = new Location("point A");

                        locationA.setLatitude(lat);
                        locationA.setLongitude(lng);

                        Location locationB = new Location("point B");

                        locationB.setLatitude(latl);
                        locationB.setLongitude(lngl);

                        float distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
                        dfi = Float.toString(distance);
                        titredistance.setTitle
                            ("Distance entre la dernière position de Locate iT et la votre :"
                                                                    + "\n" + dfi + "mètres");
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            titredistance.setTitle("Aucune position de Locate iT enregistrée.");
        }
    }
    return(true);
}
```

Thanks for the help ! :)

XML file :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item android:title="Tâches">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_buzz"
                android:icon="@drawable/buzz"
                android:title="Faire Vibrer/Sonner Locate iT." />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_distance"
                android:icon="@drawable/distance"
                android:title="En cours.." />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
                android:title="Paramètres." />

        </menu>
    </item>
</group>
```

Comment: `titredInstance` is probably null because `R.id.nav_distance` in the `menu.findItem()` call may be incorrect

Comment: Why that? Yes I saw the subject but unfortunately nothing works! ..

Comment: why is it incorrect? ..

Comment: What does the xml look like? Something like `android:id="@+id/nav_distance"`?

Comment: Yes id is correct ! I edited the question, the xml file is present

Answer (score 0):

It was a view navigation so the problem is solved thank you! We must define what we spoke menu .. ! :

```
 NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
 Menu nv = navigationView.getMenu();
 MenuItem item = nv.findItem(R.id.nav_distance);
```

Comment: how close the topic?